# Output array formula, ignoring cells in output area that already contain data

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to work on a Google Sheet and make it as user friendly as possible, so when I'm not around others can't screw it up. I have previously copied the formula down the column, but I'm trying to do it in an array formula, that is in the header of the column so people don't need to copy the formula to other cells.

The formula is simply a VLOOKUP, comparing a cell to the left with the code, and retrieving the title and other information later. (I've had this working happily via copying the formula down the column.)

```
VLOOKUP($F$2:F, 'Lessons NEW'!$E$2:$F,2,false)
```

My problem comes when trying to do this using an array formula in the header. This also works properly, but doesn't allow me to do somethings needed.

```
={"Title";
ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF($F2:$F<>"",
    VLOOKUP($F$2:F, 'Lessons NEW'!$E$2:$F,2,false),
  )
)}
```

Again this works happily.
HOWEVER. my issue is that on some rows I need to manually enter some info.

What I want to happen, is rows in the column that have data, in the array formula's destination to get skipped over and simply ignored during the array formula's output and end up containing what's been manually entered in them. (Some rows in the column will just be random manual entry stuff)

I've tried doing this via checking if there is a code in the cell to the left, and try to make it skip if so, or check if the destination cell has contents already and skip if so. but it seems that if I have anything in the output area of the array formula, it breaks it completely.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no direct solution within ARRAYFORMULA. If you can, and ideally there are no in between rows added, you can add a column to the left to be hidden, and contain the formula adapted:

```
={"",VLOOKUP($F2, 'Lessons NEW'!$E$2:$F,2,false)}
```

Without ARRAYFORMULA it will be able to expand at any row that doesn't have a handwritten value. You may also protect that whole hidden column (that will mean also that no in between rows will be added by noon authorised people, may be also useful for you)

### UPDATE

Sample script for copying the formula. Adapt the ranges and name of the sheet:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Custom")
    .addItem("Copy Formula","copyformula")
  .addToUi()

  copyformula()
}

function copyformula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
  var range = sh.getRange("D1")
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange("D2:D"))


}
```

Comment: Ahh this is a clever idea, took me a second to register what you were saying. but expanding sideways. instead of down. I shall try this. I'm happier if i can hide the formula. Could I use an array formula (or something) to paste the VLOOKUP down the hidden column?

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to do it with ARRAYFORMULA either, because of the same limitation. But yes, with some code of course:

Comment: You can add an onOpen() function, for example, or with a button, or a menu. I'll give you a sample script, when you have the formula in row 1, and it copys all through the column. It will be run when you open the spreadsheet, and when you click the new menu that will appear called "Custom". Remember to run it once from console even if it appears to do nothing, but to accept permissions,. See the update

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm not very familiar with sheets scripts, could this be to run when a row is added to the sheet. what way i can manually copy it now, and in the future, if someone adds a row it wouldn't break.    I don't suppose there would be a way to make it automatically prod the user for permissions rather then needing to do through a menu?

Comment: You can actually set an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=es-419). You can choose if it will be run by each modification, or maybe when someone opens the sheet, or every n minutes/hours/days. Look at the options and choose your most comfortable. The script then will be run like if it were by your own account, without asking permissions. PS: for this, delete the onOpen part, so you don't have the menu that will be unnecesary and confusing

Answer (score 1):

what you describe contradicts the intended usage of arrayformula. arrayformula is designed to roll out and for that, it needs an empty space. any manual input in that empty space will render the arrayformula out of the game. there are only two solutions for your issue:

- not use arrayformula but VLOOKUP formula in every cell
- use a script that will inject the formula only if there is no manual input
- and one more hybrid solution - have your arrayformula in one column and your manual input in the next column, and then have 3rd column that will gather the data like if manual column is empty output vlookup otherwise output manual input

Comment: Hi, I was afraid that'd be what i got back. I was hoping there might be a way to tell the array formula to ignore cells with data and just continue doing their thing. I'm trying to keep this very user friendly for others, so the best bet it probably still copying the vlookup to each cell which i was trying to avoid. AFAIK, using a script would require a button that i'd rather avoid having so that everything can be automatic.  I was also considering a hybrid cell like you suggested. but again, really want for userfriendlyness, to be a single sell that can either have data, or they type into it.

Comment: @MichaelLissant-Clayton for the script you wouldn't need a button. it could be all automatic. the downside is that every script needs to be authorized by every user otherwise such script won't work for such user.

Comment: Could you make it automatically pop up asking for permission rather then needing to go via a menu?

Comment: @MichaelLissant-Clayton I never attempted it but there is an option that will do exactly that. it is called an installable trigger - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119702/186471